# How to select one list from an output of multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

For example:

```
for k in range(3):
    for v in range(k+1):
        list1.append(v)
        print(list1)
```

Gives an output of:

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

How do I just get an output of the last list only?

Comment: Just put `print(list1)` outside the loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the output on every iteration. You could move the `print` statement outside the loops:

```py
for k in range(3):
    for v in range(k+1):
        list1.append(v)
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Dani Mesejo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001592/dani-mesejo) pointed out, you can put `print(list1)` outside of the loops:

```
for k in range(3):
    for v in range(k+1):
        list1.append(v)
print(list1)
```

If you do not have any code between these loops (the only purpose of the loops are to create `list1`), you can use `list comprehension` to get the same result:

```
list1 = [v for k in range(3) for v in range(k+1)]
```